# Retrieving all posts count with date sorts date wrong

Tags: mysql, sql, string, count, sql-order-by

I'm trying to make a chart where the X axis is the date (last 14 days) and the chart itself shows the count of the post on that date. However, it starts with 1. oct -> 9. oct and then proceeds with 25. sep -> 30.sep

My SQL:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d. %b") AS date, count(*) as count 
FROM posts
WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND NOW()
Group by date
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Image of the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPIgr.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `date` in the `order by` clause references the alias defined in the `select` clause, that is a string representation of the date. You can't use that to sort the resultset as you want.

Here is one workaround: add another expression to the `group by` clause that has a `date` datatype - you can then use it to order the results:

```
SELECT date_format(created_at, '%d. %b') AS date, count(*) as count 
FROM posts
WHERE created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY AND NOW()
Group by date, date(created_at)
ORDER BY date(created_at) ASC
```